# position of subview changes depending on whether calculated in cell or tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the same formula to calculate the position of a read/unread indicator, however, depending on whether I calculate it from the tableViewController or the custom tableViewCell class, the position of the red dot changes (it's too low in the cell if calculated in the tableViewController whereas it's perfectly in the middle if calculated in the cell). The only difference is that in the tableViewController I start the calculations with `cell` whereas in the tableViewCell class I start them with `self`, however, it should be the same because I'm passing the cell into the tableViewcontroller like this

```
- (void)configureCell:(MMTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

My preference is to be able to do the setup calculations in the tableViewController (for a number of reasons), however, the positioning is much better when I do them in the custom tableViewCell class.

Can you explain why this is happening

from layoutSubviews of a custom tableViewCell class

```
 if (_unreadIndicator == nil) {    
       _unreadIndicator = [[MMCircles alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18) andColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        _unreadIndicator.circleColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       [self.contentView addSubview:_unreadIndicator];
     }

    CGRect circleframe = self.unreadIndicator.frame;
    circleframe.origin.x = self.contentView.frame.size.width - self.unreadIndicator.frame.size.width - 10;
    circleframe.origin.y = (self.contentView.frame.size.height - self.unreadIndicator.frame.size.height) / 2.0;
    self.unreadIndicator.frame = circleframe;
```

from the tableViewController

```
   circleframe = _unreadIndicator.frame;
   circleframe.origin.x = cell.contentView.frame.size.width - cell.unreadIndicator.frame.size.width - 10;
   circleframe.origin.y = (cell.contentView.frame.size.height - cell.unreadIndicator.frame.size.height) / 2.0;
   _unreadIndicator.frame = circleframe;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:_unreadIndicator];
```

from the tableViewController[image: perfectly aligned red dot]

[image: red dot too low]

The image with the dot in the middle is from when it's position is calculated in the custom tableViewCell class, and the image with the red dot below center is from when it's position is calculated in the tableViewController

Comment: It's almost certainly a matter of when the code gets run more than where it is.  In what method in your table view controller were you trying to set up the subview?

Comment: Have you logged self.contentView.frame.size.height and cell.contentView.frame.size.height in their respective methods to see what they return?

Comment: @Isaac in cellForRowAtIndexPath in the tableViewController, I call a method that setsup the subview `- (void)configureCell:(MMTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: At that point, the cell probably hasn't been added to the table view, much less had its row height or any frame set up, so the layout isn't at all ready for the calculations you're performing.  When you try to do the same calculations in `layoutSubviews`, the rest of the view hierarchy of the cell is ready for the calculations.

Comment: @rdelmar doing those calculations now have to comment out some code to make get numbers hold on

Comment: @rdelmar the numbers are different. will it help to see them or would your answer be same as Isaac's regardless?

Comment: No, I think Isaac's answer is probably correct, so I don't need to see the numbers. Also, the setting up of cell subviews really should belong to the cell anyway, not the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where you're trying to calculate the position of the circle in the table view controller (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), the view hierarchy of the cell is not yet ready for the calculations you're trying to perform—in particular, the height of the cell likely isn't yet set.  In the cell's own `layoutSubviews` method, however, the cell most likely has its height set and is more ready for what you're trying to do.  That is, there's some other stuff done by the table view in getting that cell that you returned from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ready to display, before the cell's `layoutSubviews` is called, that makes your code work.